# R plot legend cropped vertically

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to add a legend to my plot of word frequences. I have 10 items as a vector to display as a legend besides by diagram. But it is cropped or not fully displayed?!

```
l <- length(plottedTerms)    
legend("topright", 
       legend = t(plottedTerms), 
       title="Legend", 
       pt.cex=1, cex = 0.7, col=1:l, 
       text.col = 1:l, lty = 1)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: Looks like you manually resized your plot. Create a plot window before the plot() with win.graph() on windows or quartz() on mac.